CP2K for "dendrimers" in solution of gas phase
I work in (nonlinear optics) and do computational studies and experimental investigations on organometallics, especially Ru complexes. I am interested in large systems such as 2nd and 3rd-generation dendrimers that are polar repetitions of the same arm units. I wondered if cp2k can be used to simulate the hyperpolarizability of such a system or a grand molecular orbital approximation.
Since cp2k needs crystal parameter input, I do not know how to input a dendrimer.
Cheers,
M
